# serverless CLI --stage param does not passed to "provider.stage"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have the following serverless.yml file content

```
custom:
  alarms:
    - functionErrors
    - functionThrottles
  myStage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  daas-aa-maturity-model-env-stage: !Join
    - '-'
    - - ${self:service}
      - ${self:custom.myStage}
      - ${self:provider.region}
  scripts:
    hooks:
      'deploy:finalize': serverless invoke -f copyGlueScripts
provider:
  name: aws
  lambdaHashingVersion: "20201221"
  managedPolicyArns:
    - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole'
    - ${self:provider.environment.GLUE_JOB_POLICY_ARN}
    ...
```

when I deploy using

```
serverless deploy --aws-profile "${PROFILE_NAME}" --stage nonprod && \
sleep 10 && \
sls s3deploy --profile "${PROFILE_NAME}" --stage nonprod
```

it generates a file `.serverless/serverless-state.json` which has the following values

```
    "provider": {
      ...
      "stage": "dev",
```

which runs into error when invoking a lambda with a "dev" in its name. Isn't that the "stage" supposed to be "nonprod" in my case?

If I do something like

```
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage}
```

in serverless.yml, it gets the following error:

```
  ServerlessError: Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
    - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.stage": Value not found at "opt" source
```

The workaround is to specify nonprod specifically in provider:

```
provider:
  stage: nonprod
  name: aws
```

But we frequently deploy the service to different env such as dev, nonprod or prod. We would like this to be automated.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: posted a solution did it helped?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
service: your service

custom:
  alarms:
    nonprod: alarm1
    dev: alarm2

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

functions: 
    something:
    handler: handler.scheduledUpdater
    
    someoperation: ${self:provider.stage}
```

`sls deploy --stage nonprod` otherwise it will default to dev
**${opt:stage, 'dev'} takes the value passed from command line --stage option. In this case prod. If no option is passed dev is taken as default**.

Comment: opt:stage does not work